# Unity3d protect code

Tags: unity-game-engine

We have a code in a unity3d game that we wish to protect from decompilation(will be published in ios,android,webgl and unity plugin). How should we protect it? Should we write that part of code as unmanaged plugin(c++)?

Comment: The answer is "it depends". In general I wouldn't worry too much about your code. It's probably nothing special. And even if I were to get all the decompiled MonoBehaviours out of the build, I would have no clue how they go together to form the software. So unless you're doing something particularly algorithmically brilliant that you don't want any one else to see, it's probably not worth the hassle. The same goes for obfuscation, which is a hell to get to act reliable anyway given the heavy dependence on reflection.

Comment: @Bart thanks but this code is important and we don't want it to leak

Comment: Then you could indeed opt for a native plugin. But all it adds is obscurity. Not necessarily security.

Comment: You are only slowing down the pepole who want to decompile your binaries. You can never completly prevent it from happening. If someone finds your binaries interesting enough to decompile, they will always find a way. The obscurity Unity provides by default is the maximum you can hope for without putting way too much effort into it for it to be even close to worth the trouble.

Comment: Is this code part of a multiplayer game that you don't want to be interfered with by cheaters? As has already been noted, any code you ship can be decompiled with enough effort, but you may be able to work around the problem by giving the game client less authority to dictate game state - trust the client less, get the server to verify that what the client says it's doing is plausible. If we know more about what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to offer more help.

Comment: At least you can obfuscate your code

Answer (score 9):

It's not possible to release software that can't be reverse-engineered.

Answer (score 0):

This is POSIBLE. Some packages have standart unity packager format. So.. If you use dynamic assets or if you use CodeContainers you need to protect your code.

So what you shoud do:

If you use dynamic assets packages: Make dll's from code or make one controller class.
If you use CodeConainers (JS) make main C# controller. After this you can extends classes or simply call methods.

PS: If you want to secure not code assets, you need make binary encoding. And when you load level or prefab you just decode this asset and use.

Comment: If the code can decode the code, the encryption can be broken by watching what it does when decoding.

Comment: with binary encryption find code very hard. Becouse images, models, textures binary too =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use obfuscation techniques, which allows you to protect your package from reverse engineering, but just from those, who is not VERY (i am talking about high-level reverse engineers, who could decompile your code and deal with ASM or could decompile your iOS/Android project) interested, in any case for [Unity](http://en.unity3d.netobf.com), [iOS](https://github.com/pjebs/Obfuscator-iOS)

Answer (score 0):

You can obfuscate the your source code using the **Remiix Obfuscator** plugin in unity asset store.

It's **free** and **easy** to use and support many platform of build on unity(android, ios).